# How do I use a nested loop to print into the output of an outer loop using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, nested-loops

JavaScript:

```
var rows = prompt("Enter amount of rows");
    columns = prompt("Enter amount of columns");


            for(counter = 0; counter <= rows; counter++){
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<tr class=\"rows\"></tr>";

                            for(i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
                document.getElementByTagName("tr").innerHTML += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
            }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table id="table">
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I get the loop inside the loop to print how many columns the user inputs, as well as the value of 'i' inside the column? When I run it I get the output of the first loop but I can't get the second loop to write into the output of the first loop. I appreciate the help.

Edit:

Okay so I tried to revise the code and came out with this. Still not working but I thought it made sense? I'm trying to make a table using user input.

HTML stays the same

Javascript:

```
var rows = prompt("Enter amount of rows");
                columns = prompt("Enter amount of columns");

            if(isNaN(rows) || isNaN(columns) || rows < 1 || columns < 1){
                alert("Please enter a whole positive number!");
            }
                else{

                    for(i=0; i<rows; i++){

                    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += document.write("<tr>");
                        for(j=1; j<columns; j++){
                            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += "<td>" + j + "</td>;
                        }
                    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += document.write("</tr>");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the question ...

Comment: No nested loops in your code...

Answer (score 1):

There's no getElementByTagName, I believe you mean getElementsByTagName which returns a list of elements.

A quick 'solution' would be to change the line to
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[counter].innerHTML += "" + i + "";

I'd recommend using document.createElement and document.appendChild if working with document elements.

```
var rows = prompt("Enter amount of rows");
var columns = prompt("Enter amount of columns");

var table = document.getElementById("table");

for(counter = 0; counter <= rows; counter++){
    var row = document.createElement("tr"); //creates our row
    row.className = "rows"; //applies a class

    for(i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        var column = document.createElement("td"); //creates a column
        column.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i)); //appends a text node with the value of 'i'
        row.appendChild(column); //Adds the column to our row
    }
    table.appendChild(row); //Add our row to the table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using jquery( no need to reinvent the wheel )
    //css
    table tr td {border: 1px solid gray;}

```
//html
<table id="table">

</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
     var rows = 10, cols = 5, i, j, row, table = $("#table");

    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       row = $("<tr></tr>");
       for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           row.append("<td>"+ i + ":" + j +"</td>");
       }
       table.append(row);
    }
});
```

click below to see working example
http://jsfiddle.net/k9z0mxo0/2/

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code fails `document.getElementByTagName("tr")`.

Try this example:

```
var rows = +(prompt("Enter amount of rows")); //parse to number
var columns = +(prompt("Enter amount of columns"));
var html = []; //array
var cnt = 1;

for(var r = 1; r <= rows; r++){
    html.push('<tr class="row">');
    for(var c = 1; c <= columns; c++) {
       html.push('<td>');
       html.push(cnt ++);
       html.push('</td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
}
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = html.join('');//concate string to build inner html for the table
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following code.

```js
function buildTable() {
  var rows, cols, tr, td, x, y, tbl;

  //--- prompt for inputs
  rows = prompt("rows", 1);
  cols = prompt("cols", 1);

  //--- range check
  rows = Math.abs(parseInt(rows, 10));
  cols = Math.abs(parseInt(cols, 10));
  if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) return;

  //--- get table to append cells to
  tbl = document.getElementById('table');

  //--- use DOM to append cells
  for (x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
      td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML = y;
      //--- the correct was is
      //td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(y));
      //--- append to row
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    //--- append to table
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
</table>
<a href='#' onclick='buildTable(); return false'>Build Table</a>
```